SOAP service - Cannot convert source type [Something[]] to target type [Something]
I am consuming a 3rd party SOAP service into my C# .NET Core console application.
To do so, I added in the service reference, by importing the WSDL
(Add --> Connected Service --> WCF Web Service).
The service exposes a method called "Order", which takes in an OrderRequest parameter
OrderResponse Order(OrderRequest request);

And the OrderRequest is defined like this:
public partial class OrderRequest
{    
    private string fMethod;    
    private KVPfield[] searchFields;
}

Nothing too exciting about the KVPfield object, it just looks like this:
public partial class KVPfield 
{
    private string fKey;
    private string fValue;
}

So in my mind, EASY, just define an array of KVPfield's and assign that to the OrderRequest:
var orderReq = new OrderRequest();
orderReq.fMethod = "save";

orderReq.searchFields= new KVPfield[] {
    new KVPfield() { fKey = "EPID", fValue = "XY111359" },
    new KVPfield() { fKey = "VSN", fValue = "HTP000157A" }
};

But now when I execute the method
var resp = svc.Order(orderReq);
But then it throws the following error:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'There was an error in
serializing body of message OrderRequest:
'CodeGenError(IsNotAssignableFrom): Cannot convert source type
[svc.KVPfield[]] to target type [svc.KVPfield].'.

Why if my WSDL's is asking for an ARRAY of KVPfield, is it expecting a single KVPfield?
Is it something to do with how I am defining my KVPfield[], or something in the internals of the wsdl?

Found the issue.
The generated C# code, was riddled with
KVPfield[][]

I just changed those to
KVPfield[]

and all works fine now.
